# How to have website (on IIS) return code 503 yet still provide local development

Tags: seo, iis, site-maintenance, http-code-503

How could I have my website running on IIS return the HTTP Header Code of `503` to the public, and at the same time be able to allow developer to continue developing it locally?

For example, if I use *app_offline.htm*, it will yield the `503` error to ALL (including the developers), but how could the developer have access and test on it?

Could we make *app_offline.htm* to be accessible to only a group a people? Or is there any other alternatives to have `503` and local development happen at the same time?

Comment: What defines a 'developer'? An IP Address? If so, you can setup URL Rewrites to analyze the IP address and permit/deny access based on that.

Comment: Yes it is a range of IPs, I have successfully setup URL Rewrites to separate the traffic! Thanks! However, I could not use App_offline only for one group of the traffic, since it brings down the entire site and beats the purpose of separating IPs. Any solution to that? thanks

Comment: You should use the rewrite rules to analyze the IP and send them to the appropriate document. I misunderstood what you were doing with app_offline, that will force the entire site to go offline so that method probably won't work for you. I would instead enable/disable rewrite rules when you want to be in 'offline/dev only' mode.

Comment: Yep that is what I'm going to do. The only down side for that is, for the "redirected" page, I'm assuming there is no way to make it return a 503 HTTP header then? Maybe just put "NO-follow, No-index" meta tag for that page?

Comment: Create a Construction index page in the TLD, then put the developer in a subdomain.  Get rid of the rewrite all together.  Once the developer finishes the work copy the subdomain to the TLD

Answer (score 1):

You might want to ask someone to migrate this to Stack Overflow as it's probably a more appropriate venue for questions concerning website development.

However, your developers shouldn't be 'developing' your live (or 'production') site directly; they should be updating another 'development' site instead and then 'deploying' changes, after they've been tested, to your production site (in a nice, easy, automated way). Doing this would completely obviate your desire for a solution to what you've requested.